# Use loop variable to make same-named function call - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a loop in an init function:

```
  fruits = {
    apple: { color: 'green' },
    banana: { color: 'yellow' },
    kiwi: { color: 'green' }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for ( let fruit in this.fruits ) {
      if ( this.fruits[fruit].color === 'green' ) {
        // I want to use the current iterator
        this[fruit]()
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make method calls to functions that satisfy the condition. The functions will have the same name as the "loop iterator" - I just can't figure out how to make the call with a dynamic name.

```
  apple() { ... }
  banana() { ... }
  kiwi() { ... }
```

So, if you look at the condition in the loop, `apple()` and `kiwi()` should be called, assuming they are green fruits.

**Question: how do I put together the function call correctly, in the ngOnInit function?**

I have tried:
`this[fruit]()` , `this.fruit()` , `this['fruit']` . What is the correct way?

Comment: looks like `fruit` variable is an object (judging by it having the `color` property) so you're trying to call `this['[object Object]']()` or smth like this.

Comment: If `fruit` were actually a string than proper way would be `this[fruit]()`

Comment: Correct, fruit is an object - just updated the question. But in the iterator, it is just a key, which is a 'string'. How can I use that value, just the value, to call a similar-named function?

Comment: Okay, so you're iterating an object using `in` operator, so `fruit` variable is a string, so correct way to check its color would be `if (fruits[fruit].color === 'green')`

Comment: You're right @Andrey , my example was just wrong - I'll update the iterator, however the `this[fruit]()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: let me check with real angular app @bruh

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/38k698o3q5 - it works, you can check the `app.component.ts` in the sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be the correct way of doing what you want

```
const fruits = {
  apple: { color: 'green' },
  banana: { color: 'yellow' },
  kiwi: { color: 'green' }
}

ngOnInit() {
  for ( let fruit in this.fruittree ) {
    if ( fruits[fruit].color === 'green' ) {
      // I want to use the current iterator
      this[fruit]();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was right, my iterator in my application was incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following to get your code working, we have to call `this[key_in_obj]()` to run the function.

```js
const fruit = {
    apple: { color: 'green' },
    banana: { color: 'yellow' },
    kiwi: { color: 'green' }
  }
for(let fru in fruit) {
  console.log(fru);
  if (fruit[fru].color === "green") {
    this[fru]();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not have a name property (my real example the value is actually a boolean). I just want to use the key name, which is a string, is there no way to do that?

Comment: @bruh I don't think this is the best practice even if its working, imaging then you have 100 fruit, will you be able to maintain your code ? You have to pass in the fruit as a property to a single function that takes care of your business. check my answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to do some logic basic on a static condition using multiple functions named as per param value in the iterator, the correct method to do this is by creating one function and passing the fruit as a property and then do the logic there based on the property value itself using switch statement (you can also use if else conditions).

```
    const fruits = {
        apple: { color: 'green' },
        banana: { color: 'yellow' },
        kiwi: { color: 'green' }
    }
    handleGreenFruit(fruit: string) {
        switch (fruit) {
            case 'apple':
                console.log('do apple stuff')
                break;
            case 'kiwi':
                console.log('do kiwi stuff')
                break;
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        for (let fruit in this.fruits) {
            if (this.fruits[fruit].color === 'green') {
                this.handleGreenFruit(fruit);
            }
        }
    }
```